# Change background color of a Canvas ScaledText

Tags: python, canvas, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm using [wxPython Canvas](https://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.floatcanvas.FloatCanvas.FloatCanvas-class.html#addshape)' `AddScaledTextBox(...)` to create a scaled Text Box.

See [here](https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/blob/master/samples/floatcanvas/TextBox.py#L65) for example:

```
Box = Canvas.AddScaledTextBox("A Two Line\nString",
                                  Point,
                                  2,
                                  BackgroundColor = "Yellow",
                                  LineColor = "Red",
                                  LineStyle = "Solid",
                                  PadSize = 5,
                                  Family = wx.TELETYPE,
                                  Position = 'bl')
```

**How to change the Background color, later, after the textbox has been defined?** (for example user input => background color change)

Comment: Have you considered clearing the canvas and redrawing everything from scratch?

Comment: @SelçukCihan redrawing the text itself? How would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this is a bug. See [lines 1841 - 1845 in the wxPython source](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxPython/blob/master/wx/lib/floatcanvas/FloatCanvas.py#L1841) - there is a reference to `self.BackgroundColor` but it's never used.

So for your example, you need to set the color of the brush associated with the text box. I've based the following off of Robin Dunn's example. The function `SetBoxBackground` is the important part.

As noted in the comments, just calling `box.Brush.SetColour(color)` or `box.Pen.SetColour(color)` can cause issues: if you have two text boxes with the same color, changing the brush/pen color for one will also affect the other. (I'm not 100% sure, but I think this is because of caching, see for example [this comment in the source](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxPython/blob/master/wx/lib/floatcanvas/FloatCanvas.py#L191).)

```
import wx
from wx.lib.floatcanvas import FloatCanvas

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.canvas = FloatCanvas.FloatCanvas(self, BackgroundColor = "black")
        MainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        MainSizer.Add(self.canvas, 4, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(MainSizer)
        self.box = self.canvas.AddScaledTextBox("A Two Line\nString",
                                  (0,10),
                                  2,
                                  BackgroundColor = "Yellow",
                                  LineColor = "Red",
                                  LineStyle = "Solid",
                                  PadSize = 5,
                                  Family = wx.TELETYPE,
                                  Position = 'bl')
        self.box2 = self.canvas.AddScaledTextBox("Second Box",
                                  (0,0),
                                  2,
                                  BackgroundColor = "Yellow",
                                  LineColor = "Red",
                                  LineStyle = "Solid",
                                  PadSize = 5,
                                  Family = wx.TELETYPE,
                                  Position = 'bl')
        self.box.Bind(FloatCanvas.EVT_FC_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnRectDown)
        wx.CallAfter(self.canvas.ZoomToBB)

    def OnRectDown(self, event):
        print ('Rectangle: Left Button down clicked at:', event.HitCoords)
        if self.box.Color == 'red':
            self.SetBoxBackground('green', "Solid")
            self.box.SetColor('black')
        else:
            self.SetBoxBackground('white', "Solid")
            self.box.SetColor('red')
        self.canvas.ClearBackground()
        self.canvas.Refresh()
        self.canvas.Draw(True)

    def SetBoxBackground(self, color, style, linewidth=1):
        # See https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxPython/blob/master/wx/lib/floatcanvas/FloatCanvas.py#L1841

        # Create a new brush (fill) with specified color
        self.box.SetBrush(color, style)
        # Create a new pen (line) with specified color
        self.box.SetPen(color, style, linewidth)
        self.box.SetBackgroundColor(color) # Now this works correctly

app = wx.App(0)
frame = TestFrame(None, title="Test")
frame.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @whrrgarbl. Maybe you could do a pull request to wxPython to correct this, or maybe RobinDunn could use your proposal? Thanks for all!

Comment: A little problem though @whrrgarbl: if there are 2 textboxes in the frame, changing `self.box.Brush.SetColour(color)` for 1 textbox in fact changes it for the 2... Strange. Do you have an idea? (It's like brush colour is changed globally...)

Comment: Thanks for the bounty :D I updated the answer with a fix for multiple textboxes (I wasn't sure if you wanted to change just background or also outline, so I included both). I think there's caching going on for the Brush and Pen - for example with my initial code, if I initialize two boxes with different fills and change the color of the first, the second fill stays the same but the border changes with the first. If I get some time over the holidays I'll definitely look into contributing!

Answer (score 1):

The `ScaledTextBox` class derives from `TextObjectMixin` which has `SetColor` and `SetBackgroundColor` methods.

Code:

```
import wx
from wx.lib.floatcanvas import FloatCanvas

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.canvas = FloatCanvas.FloatCanvas(self, BackgroundColor = "black")
        MainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        MainSizer.Add(self.canvas, 4, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(MainSizer)
        self.A = self.canvas.AddScaledTextBox('yoda', (0,0), Position = 'tl', Alignment = 'center', PadSize = 10, Size = 15, Width = 150, BackgroundColor = 'white')
        self.A.Bind(FloatCanvas.EVT_FC_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnRectDown)
        wx.CallAfter(self.canvas.ZoomToBB)

    def OnRectDown(self, event):
        print 'Rectangle: Left Button down clicked at:', event.HitCoords
        if self.A.Color == 'red':
            self.A.SetColor('black')
        else:
            self.A.SetColor('red')
        self.canvas.Draw(True)

app = wx.App(0)
frame = TestFrame(None, title="Test")
frame.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

EDIT: 
Forced a redraw of the canvas after the color change. Also, changing the background color isn't sticking for some reason, so I switched to demoing changing the text color.

Removed secondary edit because it was just creating a new text box instead of updating the original.

Comment: I added code @RobinDunn according to your answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't work, do you see what's wrong (I imagine it's just a single line)?

Comment: Thanks a lot @RobinDunn. I was primarily interested to change `BackgroundColor` and not the text color, do you have an idea how to do this?

Comment: I expect that the fact that `SetBackgroundColor` doesn't work as expected is a bug, but I don't have time to chase it right now.  If you dig into the FloatCanvas source or trace through it in a debugger you may find the reason and a fix.

Comment: I have tried many things now @RobinDunn, such as `frame.Layout()`, all kind of `redraw()` and a few other things but it still doesn't work. Would you have an idea? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The user whrrgarbl (see other answer) has found a working solution @RobinDunn, do you think it could be interesting that you include this inside wxPython?

Comment: Submit a PR and I'll review it.